# Play Framework: How to define a writable object in scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

Using Play, I have an object called `RepositoryMetadata`. I want to use that object in a method called `post`. The definition of that method is given below.

`def post[T](body: T)(implicit wrt: Writeable[T], ct: ContentTypeOf[T]): Future[WSResponse]`.

How do I make the object `RepositoryMetadata` into `Writeable`.

Comment: That mostly depends on what this `Writable` is - which library does it belong to? What's the fully qualified name (i.e. package)?

Comment: @TzachZohar `play.api.http.Writeable`, this is the package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For anyone interested in, I've run into a similar issue when using Play's WSClient. The version which I'm currently using (2.5.3) has the following signature:

```
def post[T](body: T)(implicit wrt: Writeable[T]): Future[WSResponse]
```

If you happen to need to post the payload as a json (as long as you already have a `play.api.libs.json.Writes` converter defined for your class) you could have something like below:

```
import play.api.http.{ContentTypeOf, ContentTypes, Writeable}
import play.api.libs.json.Writes
import play.api.mvc.Codec

trait WritableImplicits {
  implicit def jsonWritable[A](implicit writes: Writes[A], codec: Codec): Writeable[A] = {
    implicit val contentType = ContentTypeOf[A](Some(ContentTypes.JSON))
    val transform = Writeable.writeableOf_JsValue.transform compose (writes.writes _)
    Writeable(transform)
  }
}

object WritableImplicits extends WritableImplicits
```

and then

```
import WritableImplicits._
...
val metadata: RepositoryMetadata = ???
wsClient.url(url).post(metadata)
...
```

And that should be it!

NOTE:
If you don't have an implicit `Writes` defined in scope, you could just do the following:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

object RepositoryMetadata {
   implicit val repositoryMetadataWrites = Json.writes[RepositoryMetadata]  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to include two implicits:

```
import play.api.http._
import play.api.mvc._

implicit def writeable(implicit codec: Codec): Writeable[RepositoryMetadata] = {
  // assuming RepositoryMetadata has a .toString
  Writeable(data => codec.encode(data.toString))
}

implicit def contentType(implicit codec: Codec): ContentTypeOf[RepoositoryMetadata] = {
  // for text/plain
  ContentTypeOf(Some(ContentTypes.TEXT))
}
```

the two imports import the following:

```
play.api.http.ContentTypes
play.api.http.ContentTypeOf
play.api.http.Writeable
play.api.mvc.Codec
```

Comment: Getting an error saying `value encode is not a member of scala.io.Codec`.

Which `codec` class are you using?

Comment: Hi there, I've updated the answer to explain the imports you'll need to do. You'll need `play.api.mvc.Codec` not `scala.io.Codec`. :-)